# C# How do I get the ColumnHeader of a ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, listviewitem

I haven't found the answer anywhere. How do I get the ColumnHeader of a given ListViewItem?

The context is that I am inside the ListViewColumnSorter (custom code). I have access to two ListViewItem's, how can I get the ColumnHeader? I need to access the column's tag which contains information I put in there through the VS designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListViewItem spans all columns in the ListView (e.g. `lvItem.SubItems[0]` is column 1, `lvItem.SubItems[1]` is column 2, etc. You should know the column number you're sorting by. Then you can trace back through the ListView property:

```
ColumnHeader = lvItem.ListView.Columns[columnNumber];
```

Comment: That's the problem, I **don't** know my column number! I just get a reference to a ListViewItem. Is it possible to extract the column number from this?

Comment: @goamn I'm assuming you're using the `ColumnClick` event. If so, you should be able to get the column number by referencing `e.Column` in the handler. Documentation can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnclickeventargs.column%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: No I'm not using that. I am inside the ListViewColumnSorter, I will edit my question to add the skeleton code for it. It only gives me two ListViewItem references.

Comment: Ok nvm! I just realised there's a variable inside the code "_columnToSort" which gives you the column number ... it was copy/paste code. Thanks for the help!